# How to get the request parameters that are passed from Request made by view in Kohana 3.3.0

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

I am trying to echo a request in the view file in Kohana using `Request::factory()` method and i am sending a value in that request which i am unable to get in the `User` Controller here is my code:

The View file:

```
<h1> Welcome to My First View File </h1>
<?php echo Request::factory("user",array("id" => 123))->execute(); ?>
```

Then the `User.php` Controller have this code:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_User extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $value = $this->request->param('id');

        $content = View::factory('menu')->bind("id", $value);

        $this->response->body($content);
    }            

} // End User
```

and the view `menu.php` have this code:

```
<h2> This is the view called by Request and Parameters send was: 
     <?php echo $id; ?>
</h2>
```

when i run the code it display the text `This is the view called by Request and Parameters send was:` but it doesn't display the `$id` anyone can tell me why?

P.S: sorry for my bad English as its not my native language

Comment: Format your code, please. It will be easier for the eyes of the people that would be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Request#factory) you can see, that `Request::factory()` requires `URI` value a the first param. So, you should call something like:

```
<h1> Welcome to My First View File </h1>
<?php echo Request::factory(Route::get("user")->uri(array("id" => 123)))->execute(); ?>
```

or

```
<h1> Welcome to My First View File </h1>
<?php echo Request::factory("user/123")->execute(); ?>
```

First example uses [reverse routing](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/routing#creating-urls-and-links-using-routes), where "user" is a `Route` name. I assume that you already have `Route` for handling `URI`s like '/user/123'.

Comment: Thanks mate i wanted to know that if i don't define my Route in the `boorstrap.php` and runs the first method you described in answer will i be able to run it with default route? or i have to set the routes for User controller specifically?

Comment: You will get a Kohana_Exception, because there is no Route with name "user" registered. You should use URI `user/index/123` or `user/show/123` for default Route. I like to define special account routes, and URIs become so cool and simple: `/login`, 'user/123', `user/123-biakaveron` etc.

Comment: Thanks mate that's exactly i wanted to confirm :)!!